# Ubuntu User Accounts messed up

Tags: 12.04, users, permissions, etc, passwd-file

I need to fix Ubuntu Accounts but somehow don't really see how it could be done.

The problem is: files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` where changed.

**/etc/passwd**

*After*

```
John:x:1000:1000:John,,,:/home/serg:/bin/bash
```

*Before*

`serg:x:1000:1000:John,,,:/home/serg:/bin/bas`h

---

**/etc/hosts**

*After*

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       John-The-Rippe
```

*Before*

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       serg-Protege
```

---

**/etc/hostname**

*After*

```
John-The-Ripper
```

*Before*

```
serg-PORTEGE-Z835
```

---

I was trying to simply changed this files but can not do this because permission denied. When I'm trying to login as a root I got this message:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for John: 
John is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported
```

The file `sudoers` is empty:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$  vi /etc/sudoers
```

When I type users in cp:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ users
John John
```

When I type id, I got this:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ id
uid=1000(John) gid=1000(serg) groups=1000(serg)
```

This doesn't work either:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ usermod -l John serg
usermod: user 'serg' does not exist
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ adduser serg
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
ater.
```

Then I tried to go to the GRUB menu and from there log in as a root. I did this, but however when I tried to create user `serg`, it gave me an error that group already exist. When I tried to change `/etc/passwd` it said `permission denied`.

And this doesn't do the trick:

```
John@John-The-Ripper:~$ visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Also the last thing I tried to do is to create a bootable USB and reinstall Ubuntu, however I cannot open USB-Creator because it asked me a root passwordd. But it doesn't work.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GRUB2 on boot hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot. Then press <kbd>c</kbd>.
Now enter:

> set isofile="/boot/myiso.iso"
>
> loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
>
> linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz

In this example the device it is stored on is `/dev/sda1` and the ISO is `/boot/myiso.iso`.

Comment: From this you can run the LiveUSB Creator